# Why can't GCC compile assembly produced by CLANG?

Tags: assembly, gcc, clang, x86-64, gnu-assembler

So, I noticed that CLANG produces assembly that can't be compiled with GCC. For instance, for a simple "Hello world!" program in C, CLANG produces the following assembly:

```
    .text
    .file   "hello.c"
    .globl  main                    # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   main,@function
main:                                   # @main
    .cfi_startproc
# %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movabsq $.L.str, %rdi
    movb    $0, %al
    callq   printf
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)          # 4-byte Spill
    movl    %ecx, %eax
    addq    $16, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa %rsp, 8
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   main, .Lfunc_end0-main
    .cfi_endproc
                                        # -- End function
    .type   .L.str,@object          # @.str
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.L.str:
    .asciz  "Hello world!\n"
    .size   .L.str, 14

    .ident  "clang version 10.0.0 "
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
    .addrsig
    .addrsig_sym printf
```

But, when I attempt to compile that Assembly with `gcc hello.s`, I get:

```
hello.s: Assembler messages:
hello.s:37: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.addrsig'
hello.s:38: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.addrsig_sym'
```

But both GCC and CLANG use the same assembler, the GNU Assembler. So, what's actually going on here?

Comment: `-no-integrated-as`. Clang does **not** use GAS by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What target is this for?  I'm guessing MacOS from the `movabsq $.L.str, %rdi` - targeting Linux a compiler would use `mov $.L.str, %edi` for a position-*dependent* (non-PIE) code (otherwise a RIP-relative LEA), and Windows has a different calling convention.  It's actually pretty surprising that clang doesn't use a RIP-relative LEA here; it would be smaller than `movabs`.

**Presumably that `.addrsig` directive is clang-specific, for MachO64 metadata that GAS doesn't know how to create**.  This is probably also Apple's version of Clang, not mainline clang.

> But both GCC and CLANG use the same assembler, the GNU Assembler.

No, they use the same asm *syntax*, but clang has an integrated assembler.  As @Marc Glisse points out, you can use `clang -no-integrated-as` to disable that, which will feed this to GAS and presumably fail.