# Why does gcc not compile emitted assembly by llvm?

Tags: gcc, clang, llvm

I have a hello world program in C, then i compiled it to llvm-ir using clang, then compiled that llvm-ir to assembly, however, GCC doesn't compile the assembly code to an exe file,
i have been trying to fix this problem for a week, but i don't know why it doesn't work,
here is all the code:
hello.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

hello.ll:

```
; ModuleID = 'hello.c'
source_filename = "hello.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:w-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-windows-cygnus"

@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [15 x i8] c"Hello, World!\0A\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  %2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([15 x i8], [15 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0))
  ret i32 0
}

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #1

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0, !1}
!llvm.ident = !{!2}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 2}
!1 = !{i32 7, !"PIC Level", i32 2}
!2 = !{!"clang version 5.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_501/final)"}
```

hello.s:

```
    .text
    .def     @feat.00;
    .scl    3;
    .type   0;
    .endef
    .globl  @feat.00
.set @feat.00, 0
    .file   "hello.c"
    .def     main;
    .scl    2;
    .type   32;
    .endef
    .globl  main                    # -- Begin function main
    .p2align    4, 0x90
main:                                   # @main
.seh_proc main
# %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg 5
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    leaq    48(%rsp), %rbp
    .seh_setframe 5, 48
    .seh_endprologue
    callq   __main
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movabsq $.L.str, %rcx
    callq   printf
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .seh_handlerdata
    .text
    .seh_endproc
                                        # -- End function
    .section    .rdata,"dr"
.L.str:                                 # @.str
    .asciz  "Hello, World!\n"
```

My terminal:

```
$ clang -S -emit-llvm hello.c
$ llc hello.ll
$ gcc hello.s
hello.s: Assembler messages:
hello.s:19: Error: invalid register for .seh_pushreg
hello.s:19: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `5'
hello.s:23: Error: invalid register for .seh_setframe
hello.s:23: Error: missing separator
```

I installed LLVM using Cygwin, so that might help,
and i am using gcc version: 11.2.0

Comment: clang-5 looks quite old, did you try a more recent version? All those I have access to have `%rbp`, not `5`, after `.seh_pushref`.

Comment: Just checked, yes, my clang version is 5.0.1, i will try to upgrade to a more recent version of clang.

Comment: Installed clang version 12.0, recompiled hello.c, now llc is yelling at me 'expected ')' at end of argument list', it might be because llc is on version 8.0.1, btw i installed clang 12.0 using visual studio.

Comment: I cant post the code, since the code is over 200 lines long, and is unreadable, but here is the line that errors out:
; Function Attrs: nobuiltin noinline nounwind optnone
define linkonce_odr dso_local i32 @sprintf(i8* %0, i8* %1, ...) #0 comdat {

Comment: Feeding something produced by a recent llvm to an older version of llvm looks like a bad idea, why not use the same version for clang and llc?

Comment: I don't know exact solution for this problem but I just want give an idea from a different point of view. Some flags in `clang` (e.g `-fnoaddrsig`) can suppress some parts of code which are mostly used as metadata for debugging and `clang` specific. So, maybe using a flag while compiling can solve your problem (even it is not related to example that I mentioned), search for it. You can look a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436694/why-cant-gcc-compile-assembly-produced-by-clang. Also, you can try different compilation scenarios in https://godbolt.org site easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i fixed it by installing clang/llvm 10, using WSL, sure, it's not the latest version, but it's better then nothing.